# Remove all HTML with Regex in Javascript (not typical)

Tags: javascript, html, regex, tags

Good day. I need to remove all HTML from text.
The problem is - some attributes has "**<**" and "**>**" symbols in.

I use this rules:

```
var tmp = html.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"") // remove tags
          .replace(/\s/g, "" ); // inline
```

But its steal has some **0!">** from atributes.
Please, see my example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3nn9wmy7/

Comment: It's entirely typical, and you can't do it. [More here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/157247).

Comment: @Mariano i must use Regex, not DOM methods.

Comment: @Mariano: I don't like that question, since many answers on that question are unsafe.

Comment: I find unser from itsadok. Regex: <(?:"[^"]*"['"]*|'[^']*'['"]*|[^'">])+>

Comment: @JKLMNS Would you mind explaining why? Regex is really [not the tool for this job](http://stackoverflow.com/q/590747/5290909).

Comment: @nhahtdh noted. I'll search for a more direct answer... there should be a link in the [wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/5290909)

Comment: @Mariano, yes, you right. Easy and right way is DOM menthods. But this is test conditions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not regex so please be gentle:
in jQuery

```
$("*").text();
```

`$("*")` selects all elements
`.text()` selects the text between tags

http://jsfiddle.net/g9t3bLvz/

I hope you can go further from here

Comment: Thanks for unswer, but i need only Regex. I find unser from itsadok. Regex: <(?:"[^"]*"['"]*|'[^']*'['"]*|[^'">])+>

Answer (score -3):

I find unswer. Author is itsadok (https://stackoverflow.com/users/7581/itsadok)

```
<(?:"[^"]*"['"]*|'[^']*'['"]*|[^'">])+>
```

Comment: This would fail with escaped quotes in a string, it would also fail with `<!-- <comments> -->`, as well as `<![CDATA[`... it would fail in many scenarios.